# Pass data between services (android)

Tags: android, eclipse, service, bundle

Service A saves some information in a string array "information[]". When Service A is completed it's supposed to start Service B, and Service B should receive the string array. How can this be done? 
I've tried sending it within bundle but  can't seem to obtain the data as I would normally do between activities.

Edit:

Here's my code:

Service A, onDestroy

```
Intent is2 = new Intent(this, GatherInformationService.class);
is2.putExtra("information", info);
startService(is2);
```

Service B onCreate

```
Bundle b = new Bundle();
coords = b.getStringArray("information");
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't see how your string array supposed to exist in the new `Bundle` object you've created. Seems that you should put your logic into `onStartCommand` method like this:

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    String[] info = intent.getStringArrayExtra("information");
}
```

Please refer to Developer Guide's [section](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#StartingAService) for details.

Comment: But isn't onStartCommand called after onCreate? Isn't the main code supposed to be in onCreate?

Comment: `onStartCommand` will be called every time you calling your service whenever it's already created or not. This method supposed to handle the call. On the opposite, `onCreate` is more convenient for initialization routines.

Comment: @Eric can I further help you?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `intent.putExtra` method:

In Service A:

```
Intent intent = new Intent( this, YourTargetService.class );
intent.putExtra("YourExtraName", information );
```

In service B onCreate:

```
String[] received = getIntnet().getStringArrayExtra("YourExtraName");
```

That's should do the job

Comment: That's exactly what I have done, but it can't find the string array.

Answer (score 0):

An OOP trick around.You can make your array static and you can access that array on onCreate method or any where you want in another Service like ClassName.array = Service1.array

Thanks

Comment: There is no dangerous , we do use application Variable in most cases rather than instance variable. Thanks

Comment: Even when Service A has been destroyed?

Comment: At the time of stopping a service one can null those Application level variables . Thanks